# Why does winrar show deleted files in the folder, which were deleted before creating the rar?

Tags: windows-8, winrar

Why does winrar show deleted files in the folder, which were deleted before creating the rar?

I had a word document which I deleted from my folder, THEN I created a winrar archive.
For whatever reason, the word document is shown in the archive as in the image below:

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question; it may be a better fit on [Su]

Answer (score 0):

That's not the file. Notice the tilde (`~`) in front of the document's name. This means that the file is simply a temporary backup file. [More info here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000527.htm)

Is the Word document currently open on your computer? If so, this is definitely the reason that this backup file was created.